# How do update one textview text when the other textview text got updated

Tags: android, sorting, textview

Hi am developing android application. I have some small doubt of how to change one textview text when the other textview text got changed.
Let us say i have fourtext fields n1,n2 for displaying names and s1,s2 for displaying scores.`n1=android1,n2=android2,s1=30,s2=50`

After applying sort for scores(descending) am able to sort scores but the names still in same text view.how can i change when names too in this example.
After sort `n1=android1,n2=android2,s1=50,s2=30`
Thanks in advance...please respond soon if any knows how can i do this...

Comment: if you sort score array than in the same logic why not try to alter your name array to in same loop of score

Comment: i cant get you can you please eloborate with some sample..

Comment: i have given an ans for simplycity try an check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose in your name array

```
        String[] name={"yuvi","sachin","dravid","sehvag"};
        int[] score={15,8,89,10};
        for(int i=0;i<score.length;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<score.length;j++){
                if(score[i] < score[j]){
                    int tempsc=score[i];
                    String tempname=name[i];
                    score[i]=score[j];
                    name[i]=name[j];
                    score[j]=tempsc;
                    name[j]=tempname;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this...

```
EditText[20] e1;
String[10] names;<----- array of your names
Int[10] scores;<----- array of your scores
String[10] temp;
for(int g=0;g<10;g++)
{
temp[g]=String.valueOf(scores[g])+"-"+names[g];
}
Arrays.sort(temp);
for(int g=0;g<10;g++)
{
 String[] T=temp[g].split("-")
e1[g].setText(t[1]);<----- name
e1[g+10].setText(t[0]);<----- score
}
```

think this is much easy.. =]

Comment: ya this works fine for me thanks raju... wt abut if i have 20 textviews 10 for name and 10 for scores actually i have to display the top ten scores with names but i gave only 2 for example..please let me know how can i dot with 20 textviews if possible....

Comment: then I think you can do this[but this is obvioisly not the better way.. but just a solution...].. create 2 arrays.. 1 for names and other for scores..now i think you already have an full array of scores and corresponding names... once you apply sort for scores and get the scores...now say 30 is top score.. get its index from unsorted array.. and get the name in that index..from names array.. then you can change the names also... am I clear? :S